# How many partitions can be created for linux on GPT?

Tags: linux, gpt

I know it's up to 128 for windows OS. Does the same limit apply to Linux? So this limit is actually a limit of GPT?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/306734/334516

Comment: Also see [the Windows FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-and-gpt-faq#how-many-partitions-a-gpt-disk-can-have) on this: "The specification allows an almost unlimited number of partitions."

Comment: The "Number of partition entries in array" field in the GPT header is 4 bytes long, so the "almost unlimited number" is about 4 billion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Windows FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-and-gpt-faq) on this says

> The specification allows an almost unlimited number of partitions. However, the Windows implementation restricts this to 128 partitions. The number of partitions is limited by the amount of space reserved for partition entries in the GPT.

so the 128 is Windows-specific.

For Linux, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/585021/327880), the limitation comes usually from `DISK_MAX_PARTS`, which is 256, so 255 is the maximum number of partitions. I'd assume that this applies to all partition schemata, not only GPT.

I do not know if anything else would break if you just increase this number, and recompile the kernel with it.

Answer (score 2):

The 128 is the default setting for number of entries in the partition table header. That controls how large the partition table & backup partition table is. It can default to smaller numbers for small drives and can be adjusted to have even more.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

Full specification is part of UEFI specification.

https://uefi.org/specifications

Apple information:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2166/_index.html

Intel information:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/unified-extensible-firmware-interface/efi-specifications-general-technology.html

See also

```
man gdisk
```

Gdisk will only convert 128 MBR partitions to gpt.